# Virtualbox: trying to access the localhost web sites

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Virtualbox+Windows7+IE9 on Ubuntu Oneiric+Apache.

In Ubuntu I was hosting a web site and I could access through IE9 writting 10.0.2.2.

Now I've just created another site hosted in apache, but how can I access it (the new one) through IE9?

Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `NameVirtualHost` in apache you need to add the entry for hostname in `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` that points to 10.0.2.2 on the Windows guest and use the host name in the url in IE.

Comment: Thanks, I added to hosts file the line "10.0.2.2  my_site" and wrote from IE9 http://mysite/ and it works.